# how to div in few rows seperatly?

Tags: html, css

[image]Simple code div in top, mid, bot...................................................

```
    <top>
    <div class="top">test</div>
    <div class="top">test</div>
    <div class="top">test</div>
    </top>
<middle>
        <div class="middle"><p>test</p></div>
        <div class="middle">test</div>
        <div class="middle">test</div>
        </middle>
        <bot>
            <div class="bot"><p>test</p></div>
            <div class="bot">test</div>
            <div class="bot">test</div>
            </middle>
        </bot>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not entirely clear what your question is. Are you looking for CSS grid which will help you layout (assuming the code you have given is pseudo code rather than real code)?

Comment: Hey, i'm looking for ether html, css, or both code, that would make it look like in picture.
I want them to be separated by line, 3 div in one line, 3 in another,..When i try to do it on my own, they compose all in one line.

Comment: So have you investigated CSS grid - this is a reliable reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a flexbox on a items. In those items are your text: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

If you want a div instead of a p you can change them but make sure you change the style (css) to the class you put on those div's

There are multiple settings for flexbox to customize your layout. you can find them on the internet.

You can also use a grid: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

```css
.item{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

p{
  border: solid;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
   <p>
     test1
   </p>
   <p>
     test2
   </p>
   <p>
     test3
   </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <p>
     test1
   </p>
   <p>
     test2
   </p>
   <p>
     test3
   </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <p>
     test1
   </p>
   <p>
     test2
   </p>
   <p>
     test3
   </p>
  </div>
</div>
```